# Div click not working using phantomjsdriver / selenium-support

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am new to PhantomJSDriver and was trying to enter my email and proceed to the next screen by clicking "NEXT" button in https://www.youtube.com/content_id.

I am able to enter my email but, click event does not work.

My code:

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
caps.setBrowserName("firefox");
caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
caps.setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);
caps.setCapability("handlesAlerts", true);
caps.setCapability("elementScrollBehavior", 1);
caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, "C:\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe");
System.out.println(caps);
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/content_id");
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

WebElement elementEmail = driver.findElement(By.id("identifierId"));
System.out.println(elementEmail);
elementEmail.sendKeys("test@gmail.com");

WebElement elementNext = driver.findElement(By.id("identifierNext"));
System.out.println(elementNext + " :: " + elementNext.getText() + " :: " + elementNext.getAttribute("role"));
elementNext.click();
```

I also tried submitting the form using below code but it didn't work:

```
WebElement elementForm = driver.findElement(By.tagName("form"));
System.out.println(elementForm + " :: " + elementForm.getText() + " :: " + elementForm.getAttribute("class"));
elementForm.submit();
```

I also tried doing it using JavascriptExecutor -

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", elementNext);
```

Even, tried doing it using selenium driver -

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(elementNext).click().perform();
```

I tried taking the screenshot after waiting for few seconds for password field to be displayed on the next screen but, the screenshot captured is of the initial page.

```
try {
  (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
    public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
      return d.findElement(By.cssSelector("#password > div.aCsJod.oJeWuf > div > div.Xb9hP > input")).isDisplayed();
    }
  });
  System.out.println("We are on password screen.");
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
takeScreenshot(driver, "final.png"); // private method which captures screenshot to a file
```

It works fine when I run it in PhantomJS - Javascript code but, need to run it java.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is the error that you receive bcuz it works well for me

Comment: @kushal. I don't get any error but, its not moving to the next page which should prompt me to enter the password. If I take screenshot after click() or even wait for password element to get displayed.

Comment: I realized the userAgent property I am setting in javascript code does the trick. Any idea how I can set this in Java? page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36';

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it by setting user agent as mentioned below (just positing the answer as it might help someone):

```
String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36";
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_PAGE_SETTINGS_PREFIX + "userAgent", userAgent);
```